# Freestyle Advice for Beatboxing

Tags: composition, improvisation, beatbox

So I have been beatboxing for a couple of months now, got inspired by GBBB battles.
I can do the basic sounds (kick drum, hi hats, (inward and outward) K snares, pf Snare, throat bass, lip oscillations, humming while beatboxing, etc. You get the point; you can call me an advanced beginner).
I can do some technically fast beats (can't do tkK though).

My problem comes while freestyling; sure, I can prepare a beat and do it decently, but I have to get better at freestyling, especially at the drops - I'm seriously empty when it comes to drops. There are some iconic drops that I have heard from professional beatboxers (like D-Low, Codfish, etc.) but they seem too complicated/technical to imitate, and even if I *could* imitate them, it would seem as if I was plagiarizing, and I really wouldn't want that.

Comment: Is there no beatbox community on this SE?

Comment: Hi there, please read [about] and [ask] - your post seems to have a range of questions, some rhetorical, most of which are off topic for this site.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Is this relatively less 'broad'? Also, I don't get which question was off topic for this site. Even if it is, can you mention some other QA forum where I can perhaps ask it?

Comment: I have taken it down to one question, but it is still a little undefined. Why won't you copy the professionals in order to learn? That is what most musicians do.